# Conflicting point release versions

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, hardware-enablement-stack

I am running Ubuntu GNOME on my desktop. The following two commands give me different outputs about what my point release version is:

```
$ uname -a
Linux <hostname> 3.16.0-62-generic #82~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 19 18:56:33 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Also, isn't 14.04.4 supposed to have the 4.2 kernel?

I really don't understand what it is that is happening. Could someone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: ISO images of 14.04.4 do have kernel 4.2, but for you to get it, you need to install wily [enablement stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) to get it. That said, as far as updates and fixes are concerned, you are at 14.04.4. I see no conflict, or anything happening.

Comment: Then why does the 'uname' command show 14.04.1? Also, I had installed it with a 14.04.2 image, and ubuntu documentation says that from that point onwards, it comes with HWE. So shouldn't my kernel upgrade automatically? Or have I misunderstood HWE?

Comment: Kernels only update automatically within the same branch, so if you initially installed a 3.16 kernel, you will get updates for the 3.16 branch. If you want 4.2, just install it.

Comment: This should help answer:  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124466/what-is-the-difference-of-kernel-distributions-release-and-version

Comment: @fkraiem Ok, then I guess I misunderstood HWE. I'm okay with the current kernel. I was just curious.  I still don't understand why 'uname' and 'lsb' give two different point release versions.

Comment: @Terrance Thanks, but that was not my question.

Comment: @physkets It was actually to explain that the `14.04.1` that you are seeing in the `uname -a` output is not the version of Ubuntu that you are running.  I am running `14.04.4` with the `4.2`kernel and it shows 14.04.1.  That is the kernel version number.  From `uname -a` here `Linux terrance-ubuntu 4.2.0-30-generic #35~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 19 14:48:13 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: @Terrance oh, so the output of 'uname -v', which is the '14.04.1' string, is sort of the version that the thing is based on/compiled from.

Comment: @physkets Yes, that is correct.  The kernel can be a confusing thing sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [the wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) again. It says "If you have installed with older media you can use the following to install the newer HWE kernel derived from 15.10 (Wily): ...". 
14.04.2 ISOs do have upgraded kernel and xserver, which is why you have kernel 3.16, and not the original 3.13. 
...but those EnablementStacks are opt-in, and not automatic. As the wiki says, you, the user, should run the commands to upgrade.
Lastly, I am not sure what is `#82~14.04.1-Ubuntu`. It might be something random, for example, I am on 12.04.5, kernel 3.2.0-99-generic, and that field has `#139-Ubuntu`. Why? Don't know, but here is a [good overview of uname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943803/understanding-uname-output).